# no respone - scapy http request using sr1

Tags: python, scapy

```
 g = "GET / HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: " + url + "Connection: keep-alive\r\n\r\n"

pac = IP(dst=find_ip(url), flags=0x02) / TCP(dport=80, sport=3567, flags='A') / g

pac.show()

ans = sr1(pac)
```

why i dont get any answer? i am looking for some mistakes, but dont find.
the function "find_ip" do the right job so that is not the problem

Comment: Answers will come with clear questions

Comment: This seems to work for me. Are you running this with sufficient permissions? Are there any errors?